# Tasks for Animation Frames in a Browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser

So I understand that in order to maintain the standard 60 frames per second when running animations in a web browser, we only get around 16ms per frame to perform any task we want to. The browser has to typically go through all the steps of the rendering pipeline to render each frame:
[image]

However, experts like Paul Lewis say that we realistically have only 10ms every frame to complete our tasks as browser has some 'overheads' and 'housekeeping' to do for every frame. I would like to know what these 'overheads' and 'housekeeping' tasks actually are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Overheads" vary per browser, and most don't occur on "every frame," but it all adds up, and overhead tasks performed either by your browser or by common client-side third-party code like Google Analytics also takes up valuable milliseconds. Common overhead tasks include:

- Garbage collection
- Listening for and handling often-repeated events such as `scroll`, `mousemove`, and some touch events (e.g. if you have analytics libs that generate heatmaps, that software may be tracking every mouse operation and touch operation)
- Animations on your page (CSS ones or JavaScript-manages ones) which are "overhead" as far as the operation of your page are concerned
- Third-party (or your own) code which does its thing only after certain conditions are met (e.g. lazy-loading of images, where images are loaded (and painted and composited) only when onscreen or close to being onscreen
- Ads served by ad networks
- Your own asynchronous code (triggered by `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`, event-handlers, etc. etc. etc.) and that of any third-party libs which executes at some point, and when it does, eats into your 16ms (obviously there's a lot of overlap between this and the previous point)
- Ad blockers and similar plugins (these run on a different thread, but interact with your thread, e.g., whenever DOM manipulation is necessary or any other cross-thread communication)
- Loading of streaming media (which often consists of many network requests behind the scenes), which can include even relatively short, static videos
- The overhead of running GIF animations or video (yours or UGC) - which is separate from the previous item, which concerns just the network interaction)
- The repainting that needs to occur whenever the user scrolls or jumps to another part of your page (independent of any listeners for `scroll`, `resize`, etc.)
- The potential complete redrawing of the DOM if some types of elements are added, removed, or resized, by you or by the user
- Handling XHR or Iframe server responses or other data incoming from the network (like websockets traffic)
- Tracking pixels (loading them, handling their demands of valuable JavaScript engine time); note that large sites often have a dozen or two tracking pixels of different types on them, and all it takes is one poorly written one to make huge demands on your browser's limited resources)
- logic which attempts to anticipate what will happen next, and performing the optimizations involved
- Heavy CPU usage by other applications running in your OS (or other pages running in other tabs in your browser) which take resources away from the JavaScript engine, rendering engine, etc.
- Event-loop overhead - the JavaScript event loop is an elegant way of handling single-threaded code, but there's overhead involved in operating it

All of the above (a not-even-close-to-comprehensive list) would be considered "overhead" to whatever specific stuff you're trying to accomplish within 10ms or 16 ms or whatever.

Also note that some devices are just not capable of maintaining 60fps in-browser or anywhere; a slow CPU, lack of sufficient memory or persistent storace, etc., can slow *all* applications down, browsers included.

Maybe you're looking for something more specific, not sure - but I think I know the Paul Lewis thing you mention (where he talks about 10ms vs 16.66ms, etc.) and I'm not sure exactly what overhead he's talking about - but if, for example, you're trying to make one animation on a webpage run at 60fps, then all of the above would be "overhead" compared to your specific task of optimizing your animataion.

Hope this helps!